# Splits records based on range

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have 2 tables Item and Item Range. In Item table all items are exists in range i.e. (From and To) numbers. I have to exclude those number from ItemRange table i.e (50 to 60 and 70 to 80).

```
Declare @Item table
(
    Id int primary key, 
    ItemId int,
    [FROM] int,
    [To] int
)

Declare @ItemRange table
(
    Id int primary key, 
    ItemId int,
    [FROM] int,
    [To] int
)

INSERT INTO @Item 
VALUES  
(1,1,1,100),
(2,1,101,500),
(3,1,600,700)

INSERT INTO @ItemRange 
VALUES  
(1,1,50,60),
(2,1,70,80)
```

Expected Result:

[image]

The result in first row 1 to 49 beacuse 50-60 are in the table itemrange...then in  2nd row  61 to 69 because 70-80 in the table itemrange.. then 81 to 500 then 600-800 same as table itemrange because no range row  exist in the table itemrange..if any row find in the table itemrange in the result it should split to 2 records...pls anyone help me

Comment: Excluded how? what's the conditions here?

Comment: if any range exist in @itemRange table i.e 50 to 60 and 70-80..Pls check Result: 1 to 49 and 61-69 that means 50 to 60 are excluded.. same for 70 to 80

Comment: Alright, I think you don't understand what I mean, so please answer on this: From where 49, 61, 69.. comes from?

Comment: 49 is ItemRange (50) minus 1... and so on - as far as i understood

Comment: @EstebanP. yes exactly

Comment: @EstebanP. Okey, that explain how 61 comes, but 69 doesn't

Comment: @Sami beacuse item range table 70 to 80 exist..thats y 69 came ..also in next row start with 81

Comment: This seems quite tricky or i am just thinking in the wrong direction. But i like the question. It's challenging :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a islands and gaps problem.

You can try to use two `cte` recursive then do `except`.

Final use `Row_number` window function to get the gap number, then group by it.

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE  table Item
(
    Id int primary key, 
    ItemId int,
    [FROM] int,
    [To] int
)

CREATE table ItemRange
(
    Id int primary key, 
    ItemId int,
    [FROM] int,
    [To] int
)

INSERT INTO Item 
VALUES  
(1,1,1,100),
(2,1,101,500),
(3,1,600,700)

INSERT INTO ItemRange 
VALUES  
(1,1,50,60),
(2,1,70,80)
```

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ItemId,[FROM],[TO]
  FROM Item
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ItemId,[FROM]+ 1,[TO]
  FROM CTE
  WHERE [FROM]+ 1 <= [TO]
), CTE2 AS(
  SELECT ItemId,[FROM],[TO]
  FROM ItemRange
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  ItemId,[FROM]+ 1,[TO]
  FROM CTE2
  WHERE [FROM]+ 1 <= [TO]
),CTE3 AS(
  SELECT ItemId,[FROM]
  FROM CTE
  except
  SELECT ItemId,[FROM]
  FROM CTE2
)
SELECT ItemId,
       MIN([FROM]) 'FROM',
       MAX([FROM]) 'TO'
FROM (
  SELECT ItemId,[FROM],[FROM] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FROM]) grp
  FROM CTE3
) t1
GROUP BY grp,ItemId
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/37ba8/10/0)**:

```
| ItemId | FROM |  TO |
|--------|------|-----|
|      1 |    1 |  49 |
|      1 |   61 |  69 |
|      1 |   81 | 500 |
|      1 |  600 | 700 |
```

Comment: thanks @D-Shih...i ahve given dummy data..Actuallydifferece b/w from and to numbers are  10millions ..CTE not solution to me..Can u pls provide me alternate solutions..